# React Hooks useState vs useEffect endless loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I have the following code

```
function MyApp() {

    const [state, setState] = useState({name:'', updatedField:''});

    useEffect(() => {
        save(); //<---- endless loop here
    }, [state]);

    const save = async () => {
        var response = await api.save(state);

        var newState = {...state};
        newState.updatedField = response.updatedField;       

        setState(newState);
    }

    const onSaveBtnClicked = (event) => {
         var newState = {...state};
         newState.name = event.target.value;
         setState(newState);
    }
}
```

The object 'state' is being saved via my api when it is changed, but the act of saving to the api requires updating the 'state' object. This obviously creates an endless loop.

What is the best practice here considering I have no way of providing a callback when I update the state using setState?

Comment: What's the point of that effect, other than causing render looping? Just remove it?

Comment: I need it to save when the state object is changed. I can't call it directly after updating the state as this is asyncronous. Apologies I had a mistake in onSaveBtnClicked, so I updated it.

Comment: You may refer to the following page:

https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-infinite-loop/

Comment: Just call `save` directly when you need to. A `useEffect` hook can't update anything that is a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I went for in the end.

```
function MyApp() {

    const [state, setState] = useState(
        {
            needsSaving:false,
            obj :{
                name:'', 
                updatedField:''
            }
        });

    useEffect(() => {

        if(state.needsUpdate)
            save(); 

    }, [state.needsSaving]);

    const save = async () => {
        var response = await api.save(state.obj);
        var newState = {...state};
        newState.obj.updatedField = response.updatedField;       
        newState.needsSaving = false;
        setState(newState);
    }

    const onSaveBtnClicked = (event) => {
        var newState = {...state};
        newState.obj.name = event.target.value;
        newState.needsSaving = true;
        setState(newState);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd separate the `updatedField` out of the `state` and put it into a different variable:

```
function MyApp() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({name:'', /* include other fields here */});
    const [updatedField, setUpdatedField] = useState('');

    useEffect(save, [state]); // don't pass `state` to `save`
                              // since `save` doesn't take any parameters

    const save = async () => {
        var response = await api.save(state);
        setUpdatedField(response.updatedField);
    }
```

Then, wherever you're referring to `state.updatedField`, instead refer to the standalone `updatedField` identifier.

(make sure to catch possible asynchronous errors too - you don't want possible unhandled rejections)

Answer (score 0):

I think I cam see how the loop happens:

- you call setState
- which then triggers the useEffect callback
- which calls save
- and save at the end calls setState
- which then triggers the useEffect callback
- which then calls save
- which calls setState
- which then triggers the useEffect callback ...

I'm not sure why you need to call setState at the end of save. Does the api call in save change the state?